# Python - error 'sequence index is not an int, slice or instance with __index__

Tags: python

I am creating a TCP simulator in Python, however I am getting an error message on the lines `self.availableStates["CLOSED"] = Closed(self)` and the next 5 lines after. 
Can anyone help? 
The code where I am receiving the error is as follows:

```
class TCPSimulator(StateContext, Transition):
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = "127.0.0.1"
        self.port = 5000
        self.connection_address = 0
        self.socket = None
        self.commands = []
        self.availableStates["CLOSED"] = Closed(self)
        self.availableStates["ESTABLISHED"] = Established(self)
        self.availableStates["SYNSENT"] = SynSent(self)
        self.availableStates["FINWAIT1"] = FinWait1(self)
        self.availableStates["FINWAIT2"] = FinWait2(self)
        self.availableStates["TIMEDWAIT"] = TimedWait(self)
        print ("Transitioning to Closed state!")
        self.setState("CLOSED")
```

Answer (score 3):

`self.availableStates` is not defined before used.

Add the following line

```
class TCPSimulator(StateContext, Transition):
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = "127.0.0.1"
        self.port = 5000
        self.connection_address = 0
        self.socket = None
        self.commands = []
        self.availableStates = {}
        self.availableStates["CLOSED"] = Closed(self)
        self.availableStates["ESTABLISHED"] = Established(self)
        self.availableStates["SYNSENT"] = SynSent(self)
        self.availableStates["FINWAIT1"] = FinWait1(self)
        self.availableStates["FINWAIT2"] = FinWait2(self)
        self.availableStates["TIMEDWAIT"] = TimedWait(self)
        print ("Transitioning to Closed state!")
        self.setState("CLOSED")
```